# CreationTime and LastWriteTime

Tags: photos, date

My wife copy photos to a smartphone.

The pictures are 20160403_145233.jpg are called, are the first of 2012/03/10

But The creation date is 04/14/2016, date of transfer.

What she sorts the photos by month, are all of April, 2016.

How to change the date of creation for proper sorting?

Comment: Do you have access to a linux computer?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Sorting on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a linux computer, you can use the `touch` command for this.

Example:

```
touch -amt timestamp file
```

- **`-a`** Tells touch to set the last accessed date
- **`-m`** Tells touch to set the last modified date
- **`-t`** Sets the timestamp - use `YYYYMMDDhhmm` time format